# Gtk Drawing graphic items

Tags: gtk, drawing

I want to create a gtk (with pygobject) application for drawing graphic items as rectangles, circles, lines, and also more complex ones as UML components.

Each graphic item should be able to be moved around, resized, etc...

I see two possible approaches:

1. Define simple class with a `draw` method and appropiate attribues for each item type.
   Then draw the shapes in a `Gtk.DrawingArea` .
2. Make all the items Gtk widgets. And put the widgets in a `Gtk.Layout` or `Gtk.Fixed`
   For this approach I don't know which widget should I subclass. Maybe `DrawingArea` ?

Which of the two approaches is best?

Comment: Could you please clarify this : "Each graphic item should be a python object (currently I am using pygobject)"? What do you mean by "should be a python object"?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the link between the first and second solution... Usually in Gtk, drawings are performed using a `Gtk.DrawingArea` (which is itself a `Gtk.Widget`, which is itself a `GObject`).

Comment: I'd probably draw them manually on a single `GtkDrawingArea` instead of having each "thing" be a separate widget. Less overhead (just an elegance thing, possibly minimal performance impact) since you probably don't need the full Widget shebang (width-for-height resizing, style classes, etc.). Downside is you need to implement everything you do need from the ground up, responding to clicks, drags. Possibly you can look at [Clutter](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Clutter), I haven't used it but looks cool.

Comment: Thank you. I just installed Gtk 4 in python. It has integrated the Gsk library which superseed Clutter